# Python: try...except...finally clauses in generators

Tags: python, exception, generator

## Code

```
def gen():
    try:
        for i in range(5):
            yield i
    except Exception as e:
        print('Caught: ' + str(e))
    finally:
        print('I am done')

for x in gen():
    print(x)
    if x == 2:
        raise Exception('Catch me?')
```

## Output

```
0
1
2
I am done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise Exception('Catch me?')
Exception: Catch me?
```

## Question

Why does the code execute `finally` clause but not `except` clause?

Please give explanations with references.

Comment: you raise exception outside `gen()` function so it doesn't catch it. And `finally` is executed always.

Comment: because `finally` is executed everytime whether the code fails or not (it's like a cleanup), and you raised the exception outside the generator not inside so it doesn't know about it

Comment: Try - ```g = gen(); g.throw(ValueError)``` .

Answer (score 4):

The body of the generator function will only be run *between* iterations of the `for` loop.  That is, the `for` loop means something like:

1. Get next value from generator
2. Run loop body
3. Go back to step 1

Only step 1 involves actually running code inside the generator function.  Since the code inside `try` block in the generator function doesn't raise any exceptions, the `except` clause has nothing to catch.  The `finally` clause executes because it always executes (that's what `finally` is for).

Using a loop over a generator doesn't mean that the whole loop body runs "inside" the generator function.  It just means one value at a time is grabbed from the generator until it's exhausted.  The loop body still executes in its own scope, separate from that of the generator function.

Comment: So if an exception is raised outside of a generator who has a `finally` clause, then when does that clause get run? What if the main function uses multiple generators, each having a `finally` clause? In what order are they executed?

Comment: @Cyker: If that is your question, you should edit your question to ask it.  A `finally` clause is executed when the code in its `try` block finishes.  If your generator is suspended inside a `try` block then its finally clause won't be executed until the generator is closed (if ever).